# List<E> to Stringbuffer

Tags: android, string, list

I create a implementation of a list, so I want to pass it to a stringbuffer variable, this can be possible or not if it is possible can someone give me an example. thank you

Comment: yes, it is. look at TextUtils class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you try to do there but you can append things from a list to a `StringBuffer` for example like

```
public static void addToStringBuffer(StringBuffer buffer, List<?> list) {

    if (buffer == null || list == null)
        return;

    for (Object object : list) {
        buffer.append(object);
    }

}
```

or if you want them comma separated

```
public static void addToStringBuffer(StringBuffer buffer, List<?> list) {

    if (buffer == null || list == null)
        return;

    boolean addSeparator = false;

    for (Object object : list) {
        if (addSeparator) {
            buffer.append(", ");
        } else {
            addSeparator = true;
        }
        buffer.append(object);
    }

}
```

or use [`TextUtils#join`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable%29)

```
String result = TextUtils.join(", ", list);
```

but that's not adding to a `StringBuffer`

And unless you need the synchronization of `StringBuffer` use [`StringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)